# Steps to establish ssl between filebeat to logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I am very new to SSL and i want to establish SSL connection between filebeat and logstash.. I referred the ELK website link for the same.. I just got the concept.. And it is mostly on linux.. I am trying to do it in windows environment. Please suggest me how to do it.

1. How do i configure my CA.
2. How do i get my certificates created.

In filebeat.yml, the ssl parts which are commented says that i need to provide CA, certificate and key path.. 
But how do i generate it.

Comment: Can somebody please guide me

Comment: Hi,
I created certificates through openssl. I am trying to configure filebeat.yml for SSL authentication. 
I uncommented the ssl paths and gave proper paths as below

output.logstash:
  #The Logstash hosts
   hosts: ["***.***.***.**:5043"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
   #List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
    ssl.certificate_authorities: "C:/SSLCertificates/testca/cacert.pem"
  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
    ssl.certificate:"C:/client/cert.pem"
  # Client Certificate Key
    ssl.key:"C:/client/key.pem"

Comment: I get the following error if i start filebeat,
 
filebeat -e -c filebeat.yml -d publish
filebeat2017/05/22 05:30:24.513443 beat.go:339: CRIT Exiting: error loading config file: yaml: line 100: did not find expected key
Exiting: error loading config file: yaml: line 100: did not find expected key

Please help me what mistake i am doing here

Comment: Waiting for help . I am still stuck..

Comment: I referred the following link,
https://superuser.com/questions/606215/openssl-pkcs8-default-format-gives-rsa-private-key

i tried to convert the key from traditional format to pkcs#8 format using the below command,

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in file.key -outform pem -nocrypt -out file.pem

Still no luck.

Comment: Can some one please suggest on why i am still getting  the below error                                **ERROR logstash.inputs.beats - Looks like you either have an invalid key or your private key was not in PKCS8 format.**

Comment: Hi All,

I solved the issues and SSL is working now. 
I generated self signed certificates using Openssl for client and server.
I did the following mistakes,

1. In logstash.config, i was using **ssl_key_passphrase** which is not required. Hence i commented.
 This was the reason for getting,
 **ERROR logstash.inputs.beats - Looks like you either have an invalid key or your private key was not in PKCS8 format**

Comment: input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
  ssl => true
  ssl_certificate_authorities => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/testca/cacert.pem"
  ssl_certificate => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/server/cert.pem"
  ssl_key => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/server/pkcs8.key"
     #ssl_key_passphrase => "MySecretPassword"
  ssl_verify_mode => "force_peer"
    }
}

Comment: 2. I then another error related to connection.
   The problem with was in filebeat.yml, i was using the server path instead of client path.
   output.logstash:
   hosts: ["localhost:5043"]
    ssl.enabled: true
 ssl.certificate_authorities: ["D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/testca/cacert.pem"]
 ssl.certificate: "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/**server**/cert.pem"
 ssl.key: "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/**server**/pkcs8.key"

Comment: Gave the client certificates path and the issue was solved.
 ssl.certificate: "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/**client**/cert.pem"
 ssl.key: "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/**client**/pkcs8.key"

Comment: 3. And i had another issue also. I had generated the certificates with a particular username.
%hostname% = MyElk
 openssl req -new -key key.pem -out req.pem -outform PEM -subj /CN=%hostname%/O=server/ -nodes
 
 Because of this i had some connection error in the filebeat logs. The connection error clearly mentions 
 that MyElk is used instead of localhost. Something like that. The error message was self descriptive.
 
 I modified the command as below,
 openssl req -new -key key.pem -out req.pem -outform PEM -subj /CN=localhost/O=server/ -nodes
 
 Then the issue got solved.

Comment: Please make sure you take care of these points.